# Android - JDBC Mysql

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Как установить соединение с Mysql сервером при помощи Android? У меня есть `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar`. Но при вызове команды `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` приложение выдаёт ошибку и вылетает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android не поддерживает JDBC. Только через костыли типа http://devcolibri.com/1486

Comment: Это как раз то самое. У меня стоит Denwer, есть своя Mysql база данных. Только вот как.. сделать... А хотя может как-то через HTTPClient какой-нибудь? С ними просто ещё не сталкивался, не знаю что это такое. Пока в интернете поищу.

Answer (score 1):

Всё равно ваш MySQL находится на каком-то внешнем сервере, а не в самом устройстве с Android - организуйте работу с базой через web-service по HTTP протоколу. Так или иначе, даже если вы настроите JDBC в Android, у вас будет ещё куча проблем из-за неустойчивого соединения GPRS/LTE при прямомо доступе к базе.